# MongoDB User Is Not Authorized To

Tags: mongodb

In Mongo, I've created a database and created a user specifically for that database. When I type "show users" I get this:

```
    rs0:PRIMARY> show users;
    {
        "_id" : "sampleuser.sampleuser",
        "user" : "sampleuser",
        "db" : "sampledb",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "readWrite",
                "db" : "sampledb"
            },
            {
                "role" : "dbAdmin",
                "db" : "sampledb"
            }


]
}
```

But when I try to execute a command with that user, I get the following:

```
not authorized on sampledb to execute command { find: "social_posts", filter: { customer_id: "123", 0: { posted: { $ne: 1 } } } }
```

What permissions are setup wrong?

Comment: How are you authorizing as a user before running the command ?

Comment: Its being run via php using the mongo drivers, so I am assuming that was doing it

Comment: I think you have pass the user credentials when you create the mongo connection from php. Do your url have  the username and password when creating connection ? http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.auth.php

Comment: I do, I have all of that.

Comment: mongodb://sampeuser:xxxxx@mongo1.example.com,mongo2.example.com,example.example.com/?replicaSet=rs0

Comment: Do you have the database name(`sampledb`) somewhere in the url ?

Comment: @Veeram That is did? I have it selecting the db in PHP but it looks like it has to connect when initially connecting

Comment: Yes that db in the URL  for authorizing  the user because you can have the users in a different db.

Comment: @DevinDixon please show courtesy to give response to the answer, whether it helped you or not because it motivates us to keep answering

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [db.auth()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.auth/) to authenticate to the database before executing any query.

From [db.auth()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.auth/) doc

> **db.auth()**
>
> Allows a user to authenticate to the database from within the shell.
>
> The db.auth() method can accept:
>
> 1. the username and password.
>
>    ```
>    db.auth( <username>, <password> )
>    ```
> 2. a user document that contains the username and password, and optionally, the authentication mechanism and a digest password flag.
>
>    ```
>    db.auth( {
>     user: <username>,
>     pwd: <password>,
>     mechanism: <authentication mechanism>,
>     digestPassword: <boolean>
>    }
>    ```
>
> **Returns:**   db.auth() returns 0 when authentication is not successful, and 1 when the operation is successful.